# How to parse, and dechipher data output

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question. How would I build a method (dataCapture()) to collect the data I output from a PowerShell command within my application, and then parse the data and decipher the comma delimitation so it can input the data using the Oledb into Excel under the correct row and columns? Below I have attached my method for my PowerShell application. Any help or ideas here will be greatly appreciated! I have already built the Excel OleDB, I need no help there.

```
public void runPS()
{
    //Run query
    PowerShell.Create().AddScript(diskInfo()).AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>();

    foreach (string str in PowerShell.Create().AddScript(diskInfo()).AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
    {
        dataCapture(str);
    }
}

public void dataCapture(string input)
{
    //Do some code using the input
    excelWrite(id, volId, idSpc, idTy)
}
 private void excelWrite(string id, string volId, int idSpc, int idTy)
{
    //Does the OleDb for excel
}
```

Comment: CSV strings are best parsed with the standard .NET TextFieldParser class.  And oodles of other libraries, the google query is ".net csv parser".

Comment: Thanks Hans! I will research that!

Comment: And what do you think CSV actually stands for? It doesn't have to be a file to be CSV... Just modify the examples found on google to fit your needs. They all usually show two things - retrieval of the csv contents and parsing it. You need that parsing logic. If you can't do this, well, ....

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Comment: Don't get hung up about a file, it is boring implementation detail.  TextFieldParser is happy with a lot of sources of input.  StringReader will do just fine.

Comment: Comma, Separated, Value. yeah, after I did some more research I found other methods, most of what I found were asking me to open a file that was in CSV. I am trying the code now. I believe it's better to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx and do it myself, this way I learn and understand it better. I don't want to be known as a coder that hacks his way thru things. :) But you ROCK! Valuable input, my friend!

Comment: John, I put c# in the title so people know that I am writing in c#. I've seen some people ask c# questions and get java answers. Sorry if I upset you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388(v=vs.80).aspx

```
static void Main()
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

    string text = "one\ttwo three:four,five six seven";
    System.Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much anything directly from powershell. I did some db querying in powershell so I'm pretty sure you can use JET or OleDB directly from powershell, without parsing data in .NET.

Quick googling, this article uses COM automation: http://www.petri.co.il/export-to-excel-with-powershell.htm, maybe not the best solution if you need to move a lot of data, but should work for few hundred lines.

Powershell is pretty powerfull, so you can call your code from it, and pass data to it. Not just string, but mode complex objects as well.

#### Edit:

[This Powershell script](http://poshcode.org/1591) talk about reading from Excel, but most likely you can execute any command to OleDB, so it insert into Excel as well.

#### Edit2:

Just call your code directly from Powershell :)

`Powershell code:`

```
Add-Type -Path "CallMeFromPowershell.dll"


$result = [CallMeFromPowershell.CallFromPS]::DoSomething("hello", 123)
$result
```

`C# code:`

```
using System;

namespace CallMeFromPowershell
{
    public static class CallFromPS
    {
        public static string DoSomething(string imAString, int imAnInt)
        {
            return String.Format(@"The string: '{0}', the integer: '{1}'", imAString, imAnInt);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be `The string: 'hello', the integer: '123'`

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information, Akos. However, I am not trying to use just PowerShell to write data. I need to manipulate the data that is outputted and make the application work off of that. Excel writer is just an example I am using to point me in the correct direction.